# Where to call freeze() when working with Realm collections and Combine?

Tags: swift, realm, combine

I'd like to display some Realm objects in a read-only view (SwiftUI), and as far as I've understood, Realm objects should be frozen for such views.

But where should I call `.freeze()`? On the `Results`-object or the publisher?

```swift
Realm().objects(Contact.self)
    .freeze()
    .publisher
    .[...]
```

vs.

```swift
Realm().objects(Contact.self)
    .publisher
    .freeze()
    .[...]
```

Or does it make no difference?

Comment: It depends on what you're attempting to do, but with out more context, any answer would be guesswork. Why do you want to freeze those objects in the first place? Can you clarify the question? (I would guess the answer would be objects.freeze but that's just a guess.)

Comment: Yeah, of course. :-) It's about a read-only SwiftUI-view, I've updated the question.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but have you tried both? Are both even possible? Does the code compile in both situations?

Comment: `Freeze` is intended for situations where an Object(s) need to be passed around to other threads- just because you're display objects in another view as read only isn't really where freeze would apply, although it could. The other downsides of frozen objects is they are not live updating; suppose your view displays a list of items and their price. If the pricing changes, that view will be stale and only represent the data as it was, not as it is. In your question, it's not clear *what* you want to freeze - all of the Contact objects? If there's a lot of contacts, that can be a performance hit.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez: Yes, it is compiling, but one of both variants doesn't work. I've just posted an answer :-)

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your feedback. In my case, a contact itself can't be changed but the list of contacts can change. And the frozen `@Published var contacts` are updated, when a contact is added to the database, so it works. I know, I do not need to freeze the objects, but it feels a little bit more cleaner to me. But maybe it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tested both variants:

```swift
cancellable = try! Realm().objects(Contact.self)
    .freeze()
    .collectionPublisher
    .map { ... }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .assertNoFailure()
    .assign(to: \.contacts, on: self)
```

vs.

```swift
cancellable = try! Realm().objects(Contact.self)
    .collectionPublisher
    .freeze()
    .map { ... }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .assertNoFailure()
    .assign(to: \.contacts, on: self)
```

While both variants are compiling, the first won't work:
*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Frozen Realms do not change and do not have change notifications.'*

Therefore `freeze()` has to be called on the publisher.